# Ionic app development in Android Studio, Core Java

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

I recently started using Ionic framework to develop android app. Though it's best for web developer to use their html, css, js knowledge in mobile development, I found it useful for live application reload feature & multiple platform development with one code base.

Can I develop ionic app in Android studio with core java & live reload feature still be there.

Comment: No..ionic app cannot be developed using native platform languages like java/obj-c/swift. Ionic's main goal was to help web developers to create mobile apps in all platforms (without learning platform specific languages)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an android app.then i consider you to use angular development in which you can separate your front end and back end code. and it is very fast and responsive also. so please use latest technologies and start development and enjoy your fast app. use java for your back end development and ionic for you front end and also learn all the command before start.

Thanks